# evil "exchange-with-kill-ring"-operator?

Tags: evil, kill-ring, clipboard

I often find myself wanting to exchange some text object with whatever's currently in CLIPBOARD (not necessarily in Emacs' kill-ring, when I copy from other programs). But of course when I do something like `dib`, it puts what I removed in the CLIPBOARD, overwriting what was in CLIPBOARD (since I didn't first paste it into Emacs), so I can't just `P M-y`. So I have to copy it again, next time carefully doing `PudibP M-y`.

This feels inefficient. Is there a built-in way in emacs/evil to, instead of deleting, *exchanging* what I'm removing with what's in CLIPBOARD/top-of-kill-ring?

Comment: Did you try `C-p` or `C-n` in normal state after pasting the text?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that doesn't help, since by that time the CLIPBOARD is already overwritten. Ie. if I've copied `cheese` from a different program (so `cheese` is in CLIPBOARD but not kill-ring), and point is within `(cake)` and I do `dibP^P`, the `dib` will put `cake` in kill-ring & CLIPBOARD, overwriting `cheese` in the CLIPBOARD, while `^P` will move back to whatever I last copied *inside* Emacs.

Comment: Well, it works for me in the case that I pasted something and notice that I actually wanted to paste the earlier thing. Theory is one thing, whether it works for you is another one.

Comment: Your Emacs puts everything you copy from other programs into kill-ring, even if you never pasted it into Emacs? Is there a setting to make it watch the CLIPBOARD like that?

Comment: You still haven't answered whether TIAS solves this for you.

Comment: What's a TIAS? (I haven't found a solution yet, no.)

Comment: Try It And See™

Comment: OK, no, in that case, I did try (cf. https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/33311/evil-exchange-with-kill-ring-operator?noredirect=1#comment51487_33311) and `C-p` / `C-n` does not help (and how could they, when the `d` operator overwrites the X CLIPBOARD)

Comment: My bad, it's a matter of `(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)`.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that was a thing, thanks! Make it an answer and I'll accept it =D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evil provides `C-p` and `C-n` to exchange the currently pasted item with the previous or next kill ring item.  When combined with `(setq save-interprogram-paste-before-kill t)` whatever has been in the X clipboard will be saved to the kill ring before a kill operation, thereby becoming retrievable with `C-p`.